# How does Catch (object o) work?

Tags: c#

I was reading the blog of Chris Brumme and this code was listed:

```
catch (object o) { .... }
```

There wasn't a full explanation on this line although the article I read was on general exception handling (SEH and exceptions in managed code).

How does that line above work? Exceptions are always of type Exception (or derived)? To catch ALL exceptions just omit the brackets and its contents or catch (Exception x) will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception inherits from Object.

Thus, the line will "work" (in that it catches all exceptions), but it's still not good style.

In fact, catching all exceptions regardless of type is usually a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Will this compile?  It doesn't for me.

Comment: Catching all exceptions is good if you want to log them. Although it's usually better to use a Page_Error or App_Error event and catch them as unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Catching all exceptions != catching `object`

Comment: Honestly, I see it abused so often in the C# equivalent of "On Error Resume Next". Utterly hideous.

If you rethrow the caught exception, then it's fine.

Comment: Catching anything that is an Exception is the same as catching anything that is an Object, when the language only allows you to throw Exceptions.

Comment: It should be noted that, while C# won't permit you to throw anything not deriving from `Exception`, CLR itself doesn't have such a restriction, and will let you throw an instance of any reference type (for C++ etc). There's some CLR magic involved in this which will auto-wrap such non-`Exception`-derived instances for code which cannot consume them, however - see docs for `RuntimeWrappedException` class in MSDN. This applies to any C#-compiled assemblies, so even if C# would let you `catch(object)`, there would still be no case in which you'd get anything not derived from `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't be legal:

> ### 15.10 The try statement
>
> When a catch clause specifies a class-type, the type shall be System.Exception or a type that derives from System.Exception.

Similarly, the only thing that C# lets you throw is an object of type System.Exception.

However,

> Note: Some environments, especially those supporting multiple languages, might support exceptions that are not representable as an object derived from System.Exception, although such an exception could never be generated by C# code. In such an environment, a general catch clause might be used to catch such an exception....

The general catch clause doesn't let you catch the object, though. If you're only using C#, then I would use `catch (Exception e)` if I wanted to take some action on the exception's message, or log it somewhere; I would save `catch` for when you really don't care about the actual exception value. If you were actually depending on the general catch clause to catch things that aren't Exceptions, you should document it with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

From framework 2.0 catching an `Object` is pointless.

Earlier you could get an exception from unmanaged code that did not derive from the `Exception` class, but from framework 2.0 all unmanaged exceptions are wrapped in an object derived from `Exception`, thus there is no longer any use for `catch (Object o)` or a parameterless `catch`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in most languages Exception dervies from Object.

Also, depending on the language, you may throw anything; not just an object that derives from Exception.

This would allow you to catch these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is a Object and it can be derived, BUT the catch object must be an Exception and expression are not permitted (so or an Execption or is a derived of Exception)
When the Exception is cathed it will execute the code inside the catch and just in this scope your exception object will be defined.
If u dont put code, nothing will append.
!Note if put a derived type the catch will work just if the trhow execption has got this type

example

```
//BLOCK ANYTHING

try
{
    ...do something..
}
catch
{

}

//OR

try
{
    ...do something..
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...do something else..
}

<---- Here the variable ex is not defined
```

for custom blocking:

```
class MyException : Exception
{
    ...bla bla...

}

class OtherEx: notImplementedException
{
    ...foo foo..

}

try
{

}
catch(MyException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is mine !");

}
catch(OtherEx ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is other !");

}
catch(Exeception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is anything else !");

}
```